# Are these organo-metallic compounds?

Tags: nomenclature, organometallic-compounds

My understanding says **organo-metallic** = organic + metallic compunds.

One already known to me is **Grignard Reagent** ($\ce{RMgX}$).

But would you consider $\ce{NaOMe}$ or $\ce{NaCCH}$ as an **organometallic compound**? Would you consider $\ce{LiOAc}$, $\ce{LiOMe}$, $\ce{LiN(Me)2}$ or $\ce{LiMe}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my understanding, only $\ce{NaC#CH}$ and $\ce{LiCH3}$ are organometallic compounds.

According to the [**IUPAC** definition of organometallic compounds](http://www.iupac.org/nc/home/publications/provisional-recommendations/published/published-container/nomenclature-of-organometallic-compounds-of-the-transition-elements.html?sword_list%5B%5D=organometallic), these must contain

> at least one **metal-carbon bond** between an organic molecule, ion, or radical and a metal.

Comment: OK no metal (non)carbon bond that means.

Comment: Must the bond also be covalent? Or is ionic fine?